# Building my first kik bot through api reference guide provided by Kik

Tags: kik

I am trying to setup my first test bot in kik messanger , tried the following steps

1. I have created my test bot in kik.
2. Configured my rest api URL as a webhook URL using the kik config api provided in the docs (Not using python or node.js libraries provided by kik)
3. Now trying to chat with my test bot from the Kik iOS app , test bot is not yet submitted to the store (as it is not doing anything now to submit to store).
4. But the test bot says it is not fully configured.

Please advise, how do i test if i am using rest api's to interact with the Bot (Rest API's are developed based on the api reference guide).

Any help here is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a GET request to https://api.kik.com/v1/config with your bot username and API key and check that `webhook` is set.

If it is, I would suggest checking that you are talking to the right bot, and use the right bot username/API key when you call the APIs.